# How to prompt users to share quiz results or use of quiz app?

Tags: facebook, share, feed

I am making a small quiz, where you can find out which character from a children book series you look most like. You can see it here: https://www.facebook.com/forlagetbabu/app_471991576163640 (it is in Danish).

After answering all the questions, the user gets the results and then I would like to be able to prompt the user to share the result on his/her timeline. If not possible or if it is simpler I would just like that they could share that they have used the quiz app.

The app is written in php and I have added the code for prompting users to publish from the developer site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
      </script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });

         FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
            message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
      </script>
```

This does work. The problem is that the user does not have a chance to see the results, because the prompt window shows up immediately after clicking "see results". Can I make it appear after a few seconds or maybe direct them back to the reult page after they have shared? How can I do this? I appreciate all help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delay the opening of the prompt window you could use a Javascript timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){shareResults()},2000);     //waits 2 seconds

function shareResults() {
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
}
```

Or you put a 'Share Results' button on the 'See Results' page which launches the popup.

```
<a href="#" onclick="shareResults()">Share Results</a>
function shareResults() {
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
}
```

Also if you have the php variables for the page available you can echo them into the share message:

```
<?php
$userScore = 100;
?>

function shareResults() {
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'I got <?php echo $userScore; ?> points in the game'});
}
```

Hope that helps